# <force:inputField /> Lookup not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

> Showing a error when i am trying to access account lookup.

[image]

```
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" 
           default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }" access = "public"/>

<force:inputField aura:id="accountid" value="{!v.contact.AccountId}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] You can use reuse Strike components, just copy code to your Salesforce and it is ready to use.

http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup

https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components

The default Salesforce components do not support lookup, you have to build your custom component. However you can reuse code from here, I used it too, 100% working:

http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/07/custom-lookup-lightning-component/

Here is official article by Salesforce: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html

> Salesforce Spring ’15 release brought some brand new components ready
>   to be used in your lightning apps. One of the missing components that
>   could be useful for your apps is the input lookup component.

Another resource testifying this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XZmuQAG

Comment: I don't want to use any custom lookup.

Comment: Please see my edits. It looks there is no other way for now.

Answer (score 0):

@Tariq
As of now you don't have any other option than to create your own lightning component for input Lookup.

I have created one for my business purpose. Here is the link to it:

[InputLookUp](https://github.com/SalesforceKinks/Salesforce-Generic-AutoComplete)

Other than that you can also use  a [ALJS](http://aljs.appiphony.com/) a third party library for input Lookup as well.